# c++ Multiple parents with same variable name

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
class A{
    protected:
    int var;
};

class B{
    protected:
    int var;
};

class C : public A, public B {};
```

What happens here? Do the variable merges? Can I call one in specific like, B::var = 2, etc.

Comment: Did you even try the syntax you suggested (`B::var`)?  It happens to be correct!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You class `C` will have two variables, `B::var` and `A::var`. Outside of `C` you can access them like this (if you change to `public:`),

```
C c;
c.A::var = 2;
```

Attempting to access `c.var` will lead to an error, since there is no field with the name `var`, only `A::var` and `B::var`.

Inside `C` they behave like regular fields, again, with the names `A::var` and `B::var`.

Answer (score 2):

You can access them in class C by `A::var` and `B::var` respectively.

[Here](http://www.tenouk.com/Module16_1.html) is a link that covers the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you only refer to `var` inside of `C`,  the compiler does not know whether you mean `A::var` or `B::var` and the compiler will tell you that `var` is ambiguous. Therefore, you have to fully qualify the name when using `var`.

No merging happens, any instance of `C` will contain both variables.